# how to sort Assignments by priority in ms project macro?

Tags: vba, ms-project

is there a way to sort assignments or tasks by priority I tried this code bellow and it didn't work , I tried creating function that u send it the assignments and it supposed to return task with the most priority but didn't help a lot.any good idea how to do it ?

```
Sub SortAssignmentsByPriority()

    Dim r As Resource
    For Each r In ActiveProject.Resources
        r.Assignments.Sort FieldID:=pjAssignmentTaskPriority, SortOrder:=pjDescending
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What view do you want the sorting to be applied to? The resource usage view? Task usage view? Gantt Chart?

Comment: the resources usage view,

Comment: @Horaciux Actually it doesn't even do that ,whenever I search I found this syntax so I thought maybe I'm using it wrong , even tho I guess Assignments doesn't have a method or a object called sort , I don't know what I'm missig..